# Given $\delta{S} = \left( p\,\delta{q} \right)_{\alpha = 0},$ prove that $ \frac{\partial S}{\partial q} = p.$

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

**Context**

The context of this problem begins with the variational principle and Lagrange's equations of motion, as well as the principle of least action [1,2]. However, the problem can be cast more generally into a more general exposition of branch of mathematical physics called the calculus of variations [3].

In the standard first go found in [1,2,3] we begin  with the equation for the functional, $J$ (often $S$ is used for the action functional), and an unknown function $y$. We write $y$ as
$$y = y(x,\alpha) = y(x,0) + \alpha\,\eta{(x)}.$$
We then place restrictions on $\eta$. The first set of restrictions are essentially boundary conditions that are given by the equations
$$\eta{(x_1)}=\eta{(x_2)}=0\,.$$
To this structure, we add the condition for an extreme value, which  is that
$$
\left[\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha} \right]_{\alpha = 0} = 0\,.
$$
Running through the calculus of variation we arrive at an Euler equation. Physicists are most likely most familiar with with the form of the Euler equation called the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion.

In a typical course in mechanics, the calculus of variations comes up for a second time in the context of the principle of least action. This rendition of the calculus of variations is substantially similar to the first. There is one difference. In this case, there is no restriction on the second boundary at $x_2$. Running the through the calculus of variations without this restriction on the second boundary results in the following.
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}   = \left[\eta(x)   \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_x}\right]_{x_2}.
$$

I understand from [3] that occasionally (like in [2]) we see
$$\delta{J} =  \alpha \left[\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}\right]_{\alpha = 0}.$$
So, in this occasion,  I have that
$$
\delta{J}  =\alpha \left[ \frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}\right]_{\alpha = 0}   = \left( \left[\eta(x)   \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_x}\right]_{x_2} \right)_{\alpha = 0}.
\tag{10}$$

In the case of the principle of least action, we have an analogue of Equation (10). Now, $J$ is the action $S$; $f$ the Lagrangian $L$;  the variables are re-lettered as
\begin{equation}
x \to t
\quad \text{and}\quad
y\to q;
\end{equation}
$\delta{q}(t_2) = \delta{q}$; and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_t} $ is the generalized momentum $p$. We have that
\begin{equation}
\delta{S}  =  \alpha \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial \alpha}\right)_{\alpha = 0}   = \left(   p\,\delta{q}  \right)_{\alpha = 0}.
\end{equation}

Landau makes the following proposition [2]:

> From this relation it follows that the partial derivative of the action with respect to the [co-ordinate is]  equal  to the corresponding [momentum]: $$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial q}  = p.\tag{43.3}$$

I do not see how this proposition is true.

**Question**

Given that
\begin{equation}
\delta{S}  =    \left(    p\,\delta{q} \right)_{\alpha = 0},
\end{equation}
prove that
$$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial q}  = p.$$

---

**Bibliography**

[1] Goldstein, 3rd Ed., p. 356.

[2] Landau, Volume 1, 3rd Ed., p. 138.

[3] Arfken, 5th Ed, p. 1018.

Comment: What does it even mean? To talk about partial derivatives, you need a list of independent variables and you then fix all but one.

Comment: Sir, I have been a mathematician for 50 years and a professor for 40 of those. I know what partial derivatives are. You missed my point.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Hi. I apologize if I was condescending. I do not know how to  answer the question in your first comment. I do not see how to apply the statement that follows. Thanks

Comment: My point is that we need to know what all the independent variables are before partial derivative even makes sense. In the variational equation, there is no such necessity.

Comment: How come, there is no such necessity?

Comment: Because we’re typically relating functionals to functions, typically, rather than dependent and independent variables.

Answer (score 1):

1. OP's main issue is possibly related to the fact that one must distinguish between the *off-shell action functional*
   $$ I[q;t_i,t_f]~:=~ \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! {\rm d}t \  L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t), \tag{A} $$
   and the *Dirichlet on-shell action function*
   $$ S(q_f,t_f;q_i,t_i)~:=~I[q_{\rm cl};t_i,t_f], \tag{B} $$
   where $q_{\rm cl}:[t_i,t_f] \to \mathbb{R}$ is the extremal/classical path, which satisfies the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
   $$\frac{\delta I}{\delta q}
   ~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} 
   - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}~\approx~ 0,\tag{C} $$
   with the Dirichlet boundary conditions
   $$ q(t_i)~=~q_i \qquad \text{and}\qquad  q(t_f)~=~q_f.\tag{D}$$
   This distinction is only mentioned in words in a paragraph below eq. (43.1) on p. 138.
2. Once this distinction between eqs. (A) & (B) is made clear, the proof of eq. (43.3) is relatively straightforward [as indicated in Ref. [LL] around eqs. (2.5) & (43.2)] with some extra assumptions:

   - The classical path is unique and exists for each set of Dirichlet boundary conditions (D),
   - The classical path is uniformly continuous wrt. changes of the Dirichlet boundary conditions (D).

   For more details, see e.g. eq. (11) in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/2451).

References:

- [LL] L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *Mechanics,* vol. 1 (1976); eq. (43.3).

Comment: Qmechanic. I have perused the proof in the Phys SE site. I do not agree that the proof is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Hi. I do not believe that the first part of your answer (ie.e., [LL] only implicitly distinguishes" is true. However, it may be. The substantial issue that I have with your answer is that you refer the reader to a lengthy and complicated post, and then leave it to the reader to parse through that to find the answer to the question herein. I do think your answer is useful, especially your equation (C), where you clarify a definition. I have to review the matter again. This will probably mean editing my question to take into account what you have written. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I updated the answer.